# Can I move the top menu bar?

Tags: switching, menu-bar

As a Windows/Fedora/Mac/Ubuntu user, the menubar at the top of the screen has always bugged me. It doesn't go away and you can't move it. I've tried dragging it away in vain several times. It would look so nice on the right, just like my taskbar.

But after experiencing success with asking other questions that I thought impossible, I decided to ask it here to see if anyone knows how. So, with no further ado:

How can I move the top menu bar in Mac OS X?

Comment: why would you do this? The menu bar has no task bar (application launching) functionality, and menus of windows/linux apps are usually at the top, so doesn't it make sense for the menu bar to be on the top?

Comment: Turn the monitor on its side. Problem solved.

Comment: @Daniel L: Wow! It worked! Now, next question: Why are all my icons sideways?

Comment: That's an Easter Egg specially planted for people who want the menu bar on the side. Shhh, don't tell anyone.

Comment: Ticks for the lolz.

Comment: You can learn all the keyboard-shortcuts and delete your menubar completely with a piece of black tape...

Comment: @javadba, the menubar is part of OSX, choose another window manager if you do not like OS X. I googled this [list](http://www.junauza.com/2008/08/20-most-nimble-and-simple-x-window.html) of minimalistic window managers, but the list is old and there should be more.

Comment: @CousinCocaine  I am a heavy linux user but critical apps including JuniperNetworks vpn and Webex are either not well or not at all supported. And OS/X has great developer apps. That does not preclude my disliking the wasted real estate and their poor support for keyboarding/mnemonics. If any suggestions on how to improve within os/x (not X windows) it would be appreciated.

Comment: @javadba, each app has its own menubar, this makes it hard to disable it systemwide. You can do it per app. The key to this is a property list variable named LSUIPresentationMode. By setting this variable to a certain value within each application’s info.plist file, you can change how the Dock and menu bar behave within that application. More here: [macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/1055321/hidemenubar.html). Let me know if it works, I'll write it down as an answer.

Comment: @CousinCocaine  I want to do this in Intellij.  The Info.plist is not clear how/where to add it.

Comment: Actually, there are good reasons beyond mere taste for wanting to be able to put the menu bar on some other screen edge.  I have a MBP *below* a large monitor attached to a Linux box, with Synergy allowing me to move the cursor across systems.  So the cursor stops at the *bottom* of the MBP, but not at the top -- it just continues up into the Linux monitor.  As a result it is difficult to actually move the cursor onto the MBP menu bar.  If I could place the menu bar at the bottom, the cursor would just stop on it.

Comment: @Alexander "Why would you do this?" Because I am a Cintiq 27"QHD user and being right-handed it requires me to reach across my body and monitor to access the menu bar and having to twist my hand up and contort it, like many left-handed ppl do to write, in order to see the drop down menus—and it's the same issue in all of my applications. Having the option would be fantastic so my hand wouldn't be in the way when using on screen drawing/input devices.

Comment: Take a look at my answer: as of `El Capitan` the menu bar may now be **auto-hidden**

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, why would you use Webex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only moving of the menu bar you can do is from monitor to monitor.

[SecondBar](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33264/secondbar) gives you, well, a second menu bar. It is draggable, so you could position it in the middle or bottom of your screen, but I can't get it to change orientations to go vertically on the right.

Comment: Aww, dang. Now my vision of Apple.SE as a place where everything has an answer is ruined. :(

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp Dashed on the ground like so many iPads.

Comment: I'll give this a day and see if anyone turns up with anything. After that, you get the green check.

Comment: JavaAndCSharp, everything DOES have an answer here. The answer is that the Mac menu bar has been fixed at the top of the screen since 1984 and you can't move it. Apple INVENTED the menu bar and pull-down menus with commands, so they established this convention and they've never departed from it. Windows, on the other hand, circa 1987, was designed with every app having its own menu bar in its own window, which could be moved.

Comment: @Wheat Williams: I meant a *satisfactory* answer. Now leave me be to cry in the corner with my non-movable menu bar. :(

Comment: You'll probably grow to wonder how you ever used it anywhere else. :)

Comment: Okay, it's been long enough. Green check for you.

Comment: @StevenFisher five years mac-only and I still really would like to move the menu bar.  All laptops have well more horizontal than vertical real estate

Comment: The link is not working anymore

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 The app seems to be no longer under development (likely because recent versions of macOS display a menu bar on multiple monitors), but I've updated the answer to include a link to MacUpdate, which still provides a download for it: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33264/secondbar

Answer (score 8):

You can not re-position the menu bar, but you can configure it to be hidden when idle by checking the option 'Automatically hide and show the menu bar' under the General tab of System Preferences. Screenshot provided for further clarification. [image]

Answer (score 5):

The top menu bar is non-moveable since the first version of MacOS and later Mac OS X.

You can't move it (tho you can drag it to an external display if you have one).

Comment: Think different.. great..

Comment: @javadba so different that Ubuntu linux also went with the same approach.

Comment: I have several ubuntu laptops, all of which I have changed the top menubar to be (a) on the left side and (b) autohide. So what are you talking about? Point is it is configurable in ubuntu.

Comment: The point is, if you don't like the way OS X does things, you just use something else as opposed to leaving pointless rants that nobody really cares about :)

Comment: I have not "given up" on  those two issues being resolvable - thus my continued comments.

Comment: It's not an issue for a lot of users, so there's nothing to resolve. It's been designed to be there and will probably remain there until they decide to come up with something different. It makes a lot of sense to be there, it's not a big deal, you can get used to it in one day and it really doesn't make you less (or more?) productive. It's an easy to hit target area. Even if you'd love to move it, you can't on OSX, you so you have to adapt or just install other OS, but it will not be "resolved" per se.

Comment: fyi I finally found a good workaround and have added an answer with it.

Comment: Well, you still can’t move it, so this is not really a workaround. El Capitan was released a long time ago. :)

Comment: Actually it is a workaround for the considerations that brought me to this question/post: saving real estate and removing distractions.

Comment: As someone forced to move from Ubuntu to Mac for work, no I can't use something else unless I want to give up my job.  Not constructive.

Comment: I haven't used macOS (or OS X) since 2018 so I understand where this comes from. I actually do like the persistent macOS menubar. It's perhaps *the only* thing I like about macOS. :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers the menu bar can unfortunately not be ***moved***. However  - **as of El Capitan** - it is possible to ***hide*** it!

It is in `General | Appearance | Automatically hide and show the menu bar`:

[image]

**No top menu bar!**

[image]

I appreciate this additional vertical real estate as well as diminished visual distraction.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't

move the menu bar to your application top. This is a designed function from the original **[desktop metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_metaphor)**. This is providing both an ergonomic (it's faster to move to a fix location) and a security function (this area is protected,
and thus can never get hidden).

### You can

move your keyboard to the menu bar:

<kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

and from there access any menu entry without touching the trackpad and faster than any mouse addict.

Comment: It is a "you don't know any better" feature.  I have long ago memorized all of the menu items from my IDE and it takes up valuable vertical space. Well in any case noone on this thread made that decision.

Comment: You can. You only do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can by holding <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> while moving the icons but it would only work for the bars that were created by apple.

Comment: got pic?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏